# i cannot get the url from Mozilla and Opera browsers using c#

Tags: c#

Help me please. How could I get the url from the address bar. Im using c# for this. it is window application

for example: if I type www.google.com in my address bar, then i would get "www.google.com" caption.

I have already done this to IExplorer, it was successful but i cannot get the url from Mozilla and Opera browsers. Kindly help

Comment: And what is the app? a win exe? or an ASP.NET site (which would only have access to javascript)?

Comment: I second Marc.  What are you talking about?  Is this a server app, a browser addon, or what?  What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using C# in an ASP .Net Page you can use

```
string url = Request.Path;
```

Or Request.Url contains URI information

```
Uri uri = Request.Url
```

If you're using Javascript on the client then use

```
var url = window.location;
```

Comment: Good answer for a very vague question.